# Why isn't there a standard C++ math library <math> instead the C wrapper <cmath>?

Tags: c++, stl

C++ standard introduces new APIs while keeping compatible with C APIs. The headers of C wrappers begin with "c" such as <ctime>, <cstring> and <climits>. Their correspondent C++ headers are <chrono>, <string> and <limits>.

My question is why STL doesn't provide a new math library even though there are a number of flaws in old C APIs. The flaws include but are not limited to: C API uses "f", "l" and "ll" prefix to declare functions for different types whereas C++ can overload, lack of constants such as pi and e, etc.

Answer (score 6):

There is a C++ standard library version of C's `<math.h>`: it's `<cmath>`. The `<cfoo>` headers are *not* merely wrappers of `<foo.h>` with the names in the `std` namespace. They use some C++ features, such as function overloading, and can have a lot more features. For example, `<cmath>` has a bunch of [special mathematical functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cmath#Special_mathematical_functions)

Consider `std::abs`. In `<cmath>`, there are overloads for [`int`, `long`, and `long long`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/abs), as well as [`float`, `double`, and `long double`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/fabs).

Answer (score 2):

`<cmath>` is a standard library header of C++ which is extended from C header `<math.h>` and comes with namespace `std`.

Since C++ 17, special mathematical functions were merged into the standard from TR1 and linear interpolation function (C++ 20) which were included inside `<cmath>` header.

Some mathematical functions were included inside `<numeric>` such as the constexpr functions `gcd`, `lcd`, and `midpoint` (from C++ 20).

Mathematical constants were added in C++ 20, which were included in a separate header called `<numbers>` and enclosed inside namespace `std::numbers`.

There are still flaws you can find from the standard math library which includes the inconsistency of function overloads due to backward compatibility with C and some mathematical concepts were included in separate headers.